# USB multiboot: Everything except Clonezilla works

Tags: boot, usb-flash-drive, grub, clonezilla

I am trying to add the Clonezilla live iso to my multiboot USB key. Every other distro seems to work, but Clonezilla boots to the prompt

```
(initramfs)
```

instead of launching properly.

I have modified the original menuentry in the same way I did the others and even tried the `findiso` parameter I found while reading old forum posts. It did not help.

The setup consists of grub installed on a 8GB vfat USB key with the config in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` and the images in `/isos/`. This is my config (clonezilla one last, with the original entry appended).

What am I missing?

```
menuentry "Ubuntu 13.04 64bit" {
    set iso="/iso/ubuntu-13.04-desktop-amd64.iso"
    loopback loop $iso
    linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz.efi boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$iso noprompt noeject
    initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
}

menuentry "Ubuntu 13.04 32bit" {
    set iso="/iso/ubuntu-13.04-desktop-amd32.iso"
    loopback loop $iso
    linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$iso noprompt noeject
    initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
}

menuentry "Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS 64bit" {
    set iso="/iso/ubuntu-12.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso"
    loopback loop $iso
    linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$iso noprompt noeject
    initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
}

menuentry "Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS 32bit" {
    set iso="/iso/ubuntu-12.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso"
    loopback loop $iso
    linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$iso noprompt noeject
    initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
}

menuentry "Mint 16 Cinnamon 32bit" {
    set iso="/iso/linuxmint-16-cinnamon-dvd-32bit.iso"
    loopback loop $iso
    linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$iso noprompt noeject
    initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
}

menuentry "Mint 16 Cinnamon 64bit" {
    set iso="/iso/linuxmint-16-cinnamon-dvd-64bit.iso"
    loopback loop $iso
    linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$iso noprompt noeject
    initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
}

menuentry "Debian 7.4.0 64bit" {
    set iso="/iso/debian-7.4.0-amd64-netinst.iso"
    loopback loop $iso
    linux (loop)/install.amd/vmlinuz
    initrd (loop)/install.amd/initrd.gz
}

menuentry "Debian 7.4.0 32bit" {
    set iso="/iso/debian-7.4.0-i386-netinst.iso"
    loopback loop $iso
    linux (loop)/install.386/vmlinuz
    initrd (loop)/install.386/initrd.gz
}

menuentry "memtest86+" {
    linux16 /iso/mt86plus
}

# My entry:
menuentry "Clonezilla 32bit to RAM" {
    set iso="/iso/clonezilla-live-20140114-saucy-i386.iso"
    loopback loop $iso
    linux (loop)/live/vmlinuz boot=live username=user hostname=saucy config quiet union=overlayfs noswap edd=on nomodeset noeject locales= keyboard-layouts= ocs_live_run="ocs-live-general" ocs_live_extra_param="" ocs_live_batch=no video=uvesafb:mode_option=800x600-16 toram=filesystem.squashfs ip=  splash i915.blacklist=yes radeonhd.blacklist=yes nouveau.blacklist=yes vmwgfx.enable_fbdev=no findiso=$iso
    initrd (loop)/live/initrd.img
}

# Clonezilla live original:
menuentry "Clonezilla live (To RAM, boot media can be removed later)"{
  search --set -f /live/vmlinuz
  linux /live/vmlinuz boot=live username=user hostname=saucy config quiet union=overlayfs noswap edd=on nomodeset noeject locales= keyboard-layouts= ocs_live_run="ocs-live-general" ocs_live_extra_param="" ocs_live_batch=no video=uvesafb:mode_option=800x600-16 toram=filesystem.squashfs ip=  splash i915.blacklist=yes radeonhd.blacklist=yes nouveau.blacklist=yes vmwgfx.enable_fbdev=no
  initrd /live/initrd.img
}
```

Pasted in its entirety in case someone wants to use it. Original file names as of 140221.

Answer (score 1):

Even though it's been quite a while since this question was asked, I'll still give an answer.

After testing my own menuenty for the latest **Ubuntu** based version of the clonezilla iso,
I compared it with yours. Turns out they were identical. But I did get it to work. Do note though that from my tests it took about 1-2 minutes before anything appeared on the screen while booting.

For the **Debian** based version, the following menu entry worked for me with the latest Clonezilla iso:

```
menuentry "Clonezilla live (To RAM, boot media can be removed later)"{
    set isofile="/iso/clonezilla-live-2.2.2-32-i486.iso"
    loopback loop $isofile
    linux (loop)/live/vmlinuz boot=live username=user config quiet noswap edd=on nomodeset noeject locales= keyboard-layouts= ocs_live_run="ocs-live-general" ocs_live_extra_param="" ocs_live_batch=no vga=788 toram=filesystem.squashfs ip=  nosplash i915.blacklist=yes radeonhd.blacklist=yes nouveau.blacklist=yes vmwgfx.enable_fbdev=no findiso=$isofile
    initrd (loop)/live/initrd.img
}
```

Comment: Is this the debian based Clonezilla? The one i have is the ubuntu based one. If I remember correctly it was something about extra drivers...

Comment: @tommyo Yes, I am using the Debian based version. Note that you only need to use the Ubuntu version if you really need the property drivers. In any case, tomorrow I'll try and see if I can get the Ubuntu based version to work.

Comment: @tommyo OK, so I went ahead and tested the Ubuntu version. Didn't have a problem. Will update my answer, and share the menu entry. From my tests, it does take a while (about 1-2 minutes) before anything appears on the screen

Comment: @tommyo Turns out my code was exactly the same as yours o.O

Comment: @Isacc: Well, that is confusing.

Comment: @tommyo Hmmm... Could you try updating to the latest ISO? (In case there is a bug causing a problem in the version you are using.)
Also: Let it sit for at least 5 minutes, as it can take a while.